# Revert back to Winter 16 Force.com IDE in eclipse?

Tags: force.com, eclipse

My target orgs are all still on Winter 16, and I just learned, unfortunately, that I cannot fetch from them after running the updates for Force.Com IDE which will now only access Spring 16 instances.  Does anyone know if I can uninstall and alter the url to grab an earlier version of Force.com IDE?

Thank you for any assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to take a look at .settings/com.salesforce.ide.core.prefs

Here's mine:

```
eclipse.preferences.version=1
endpointApiVersion=35.0
endpointEnvironment=Sandbox
endpointServer=test.salesforce.com
httpsProtocol=true
ideVersion=35.0
keependpoint=false
metadataFormatVersion=35.0
namespacePrefix=
packageName=unpackaged
preferToolingDeployment=true
projectIdentifier=IDE-4569797042840404286
readTimeout=400
username=me@my.org
```

I'd guess that you have endpointApiVersion, ideVersion, metadataFormatVersion all set to 36 (Assuming Force.com IDE is in lock-step with api versions)

Try bumping them back to 35, and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you Powlo!  I removed Force.com IDE and did a new install by unchecking "Show only the latest versions of available software."  Then I was able to grab version 35.  Thanks for your help!